# Jaspser Reports Detail Dyanmic Column Width

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a JasperReport file with the basic header/detail/footer bands. In my Details, I have a Column Header row in a Grid Layout and a Detail Row, also in a GridLayout.  I'm having a few issues with this Detail section.  I have 3 columns that I'm hiding with an expression using printWhenExpression=$P{Exp1}. This works to hide the field, but the rest of the columns in the detail section don't adjust to this.  So I'm left with a giant blank column in the middle of my detail section.

I'm coming from Crystal Reports where I could just suppress fields and the CR would adjust widths as necessary. I can't seem to find anything to do the same with JasperReports, which doesn't make much sense since I would expect a GridLayout to try and fill up the space as needed.  So is there any way to have a table/grid like layout that will adjust column widths to fill the available space when a field is hidden.

Comment: add some examples/sample code?

Comment: Crosstable (but it will not fill available space, just generate the columns you need) or you need to use dynamic jasper, dynamic report.